# Lag in HTML Outputs within R

Tags: html, r, search, leaflet, interactive

I found this post on stackoverflow to make an interactive map in R (second answer): [Search button for Leaflet R map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798690/search-button-for-leaflet-r-map)

```
library(leaflet)
library(inlmisc)
df = read.csv(textConnection(
'Name, Lat, Long
<b>location 1</b>,42.3401, -71.0589
<b>location 2</b>,42.3501, -71.0689'))

map=leaflet(df) %>% 
addTiles() %>%
setView(lng=-71.0589,lat=42.3301, zoom=12) %>%
addMarkers(~Long, ~Lat, popup = ~Name, group="marker")    

map=inlmisc::AddSearchButton(map, group = "marker", zoom = 15,
                            textPlaceholder = "Search here")
```

This code works and produces a map:

[image]

But for some reason, when I try to search for one of the locations (e.g. "location 1") - the map seems to take a long time to load and experience a lot of lag. As such, I have waited several minutes and was unable to actually search for one of these cities.

Can someone please help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs when there is no label given for the locations.

```
library(leaflet)
library(inlmisc)

df <- read.csv(textConnection(
  'Name, Lat, Long, Label,
  <b>location 1</b>,42.3401, -71.0589, Loc 1
  <b>location 2</b>,42.3501, -71.0689, Loc 2'))

map <- leaflet(df) %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(lng=-71.0589,lat=42.3301, zoom=12) %>%
  addMarkers(~Long, ~Lat, popup = ~Name, group="marker", label = ~Label) %>% 
  inlmisc::AddSearchButton(group = "marker", zoom = 15,
                       textPlaceholder = "Search here")
```